# Changing UINavigationBar to transparent color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I want my UINavigationBar to be completely transparent except for the title and the buttons I add to it.

I just can't seem to make it work. I've tried everything already. This made the most sense to me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.title = "CURRENT BALANCE"

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

    self.setupSideMenu()

    self.topUpButton.asCircle()
    self.exchangeButton.asCircle()
    self.lockButton.asCircle()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Check this out: https://gyazo.com/728a1cf8ad12356ce05a024ce4f0c252 Can you share  any demo project?

Comment: That is exactly what I want! I do not understand why it's not happening on my device/simulator :(

Comment: Can you share demo? Or you mail me on my mail.

Comment: What do you mean with a demo? I can email you the project later if I don't find a solution through this channel.

Comment: Lol... found the solution, I'm so stupid. My Views background is white....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my OC code to make UINavigationBar to be completely transparent:

first set the VC to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, then override `- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`

```
    // change the backgroudcolor black
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.000 green:0.000 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000];
    // change the alpha 0.3
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.300;
    // change the translucent YES
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

mainwhile, check your code about the `self.view.backgroudcolor`, if any view under your `UINavigationBar` have a backgroudcolor, your `UINavigationBar` will display the view's color.

Comment: i think `swift` also can do this ,but my swift is very poor.

Comment: I was able to translate your code to Swift but it didn't make a difference for me

Comment: did you set the `self.view.backgroudcolor` ? check this .

Comment: I did not, setting the self.view.backgroundcolor was indeed the problem.

Comment: Please add the comment in your answer so I can accept your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Set background color property of navigation bar

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Update:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetricsDefault)
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference for me

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans Updated my answer kindly try this & let me know.

Comment: Found the solution. The underlying view had a white background so the bar was already transparent.

Answer (score 1):

This is transparent NavigationController code for swift 4:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}
```

Comment: use self.navigationController?.navigationBar instead of self.navigationBar will works fine